# I was studying about probable error and I couldn't understand the reason behind using 0.6745 of standard error. Could someone please explain it?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-error

P.E=0.6745(S.E)

Probable Error = 0.6745 × 1−r2/√N

Comment: If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $P(X \le \mu+ 0.6745\sigma) \approx \frac34$ so $P(\mu - 0.6745\sigma \le X \le \mu+ 0.6745\sigma) \approx \frac12$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understand the standard deviation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438336/understand-the-standard-deviation)

Comment: @Carl I cannot find any mention of $0.6745$ in that thread.  Please note that this is *not* an approximation for the $68.2689\ldots\%$ that appears there!

Comment: @whuber Indeed, my bad. The post is cryptic so it was easy to misunderstand it. I prefer more explicit text where abbreviations are spelt out, rather than assumed, and equations that are formatted properly.

Comment: If you would click through the "Details" link in the Wikipedia stub on "probable error" you will find the explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation#Relation_to_standard_deviation.  That page highlights the importance of the assumption of a Normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

For a symetric distribution the probable error is equal to the [median absolute deviation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation), which is related to the standard deviation as
$$MAD=0.67449\sigma.$$

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probable_error):

> In statistics, probable error defines the half-range of an interval about a central point for the distribution, such that half of the values from the distribution will lie within the interval and half outside. **Thus for a symmetric distribution it is equivalent to half the interquartile range, or the median absolute deviation.**

Comment: I believe the question is asking for the reason why the strange constant 0.67449 appears.  The answer lies in the comments to the question.

Comment: @whuber it is derived in the cited WIkipedia article.

Comment: Burying the whole point of the question in a reference to Wikipedia is a rather elliptical way to answer it!

Comment: @whuber This is not how I understood the question. My interpretation was *why constant is there / Where does it come from*. And the answer is : because one uses MAD rather than $\sigma$ and the two are linearly related to each other. I will think how to accomodate your interpretation.

Comment: The two are not generally linearly related to each other: this is only when one adopts specific kinds of distributional assumptions, such as a location-scale family.  In any other situation there usually is not a linear relation between $\sigma$ and MAD.

Comment: @whuber thanks for this precision.